# A space with an isometry group of $\operatorname{Spin}(d)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, isometry

A space which has an isometry group of $O(n)$ is $S^{n-1}$.

A space which has an isometry group of $U(n)$ is $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ excludes an origin.

> Which space has an isometry group of $\operatorname{Spin}(d)$:
>
> - When $d$ is even?
> - When $d$ is odd?

Note that $Spin(d)/(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})=SO(d)$ --  $Spin(d)$ is a universal cover of $SO(d)$.

Comment: I'm interested in this question, but could you say precisely what "has an isometry" means?

Comment: has an isometry --> "has an isometry group" thanks +1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group

Comment: What metric are you putting on $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the origin removed to get an isometry group of $U(n)$?